# Save JSON String in Object

Tags: json, swift, string, serialization, encoding

i want to save a JSON-String into an existing Object in Swift:

This is my Object:

```
struct Benutzer : Decodable, Encodable{
let userRights: [String]
}
```

This is my String:

```
str = "{"user_rights":["terminal_create"]}"
```

That is my Code:

```
do { let data1 = str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)

let User = try JSONDecoder().decode(Benutzer.self, from: data1 as Data)

print(User)

 }catch{
       print("Error serializing!")
  }
```

With this code, "Error serializing!" shows up every time. Do you guys know whats up? Sorry, I am still a complete beginner. Sorry for not formatting the question I don't quite get it :( I get this String from another JSON request: I get this as an answer, the JSON data string that I want to decode is part of that answer:

Answer(api_version: 1, result: "login", success: true, token: "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709", data: "{\"user_rights\":[\"terminal_create\"]}")

This is a Answer-Object:

```
struct Answer: Decodable, Encodable{

    let api_version: Int
    let result: String
    let success: Bool
    let token: String
    let data: String

}
```

Maybe you know another way how to extract that Data into a Benutzer Object.
I would be really thankful, thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Show us the exact value of `str`. And print the error in your `catch`: `print("Error serializing: \(error)")`.

Comment: str = String = "{"user_rights":["terminal_create"]}"

Comment: Error serializing: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "userRights", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"userRights\", intValue: nil) (\"userRights\").", underlyingError: nil))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your coding key not similar to what in your string  `userRights`   , `user_rights`

so do like that:

```
struct Benutzer: Codable {
        let userRights: [String]

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case userRights = "user_rights"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much I completely overlooked that! Now it works. Thanks!